# Angularjs: How to make service/factory get data from provider

Tags: angularjs

I am really trying to understand how provider configuration works.. i have a service which only makes http calls. let's say it goes like this:

```
module.service("$myService", ["$http", function($http){
    this.get = function(url, headers){
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            headers: headers || {}
        });
    };
}]);
```

i know providers are set with the `provider` recipe, but all the examples i have seen so far have not yet cleared me on how they can provide the configured data to factories and services.

for the moment i just want a simple data to be available to the whole module which can be configured.

```
module.provider("myProvider", [function(){
    return {
        setDomain: function(value){
            this.Domain = value
        }
    }
}]);

module.config(["myProvider", function($myProvider){
    $myProvider.setDomain("localhost");
}]);
```

in here is quite a simple example (not exactly how provider works) on how i would like to configure the provider with the data which will be used to all services and factories registered to the module. So again, how could i make the data set from providers be accesible from the services/factories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two basic types of services in Angular - `constant` and `provider`. All other types of services are derivatives of `provider`.

`service` and `factory` are [syntactic sugar](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/auto/injector.js#L723-L733) for `provider`. They are supposed to be used when service provider shouldn't be configured. And `provider` is supposed to be used instead when service provider should be configured. Thus, `provider` is responsible for configuring it's own provider only.

For your case

> i just want a simple data to be available to the whole module which can be configured.

`constant` service is a match, this is what it is for. It can't have dependencies but is available for injection in both config and run phases.

```
module.constant("myConstant", {
    setDomain: function(value){
        this.Domain = value
    }
});
```

Comment: This was actually the kind of explanation i was looking for, i did not know that constant could be used in config phase.. Just for curiosity, it isn't wrong if i call the constant like "myModuleProvider"? with this i would be able to call it that way on the config even though it's not actually a provider

Comment: Calling it like that would be semantically incorrect, because it isn't a real provider. `constant` makes a service available for injection with the same name (myConstant) [in both config and run phases](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/auto/injector.js#L737-L741), as opposed to `provider` and its derivatives that have `Provider` suffix in config phase.

Comment: alright, i will call my constant as "myModule". so this wouldn't be wrong and the way to call it through config would be with the name "myModule"

Comment: Yes, it will be injected as `myModule` everywhere.